# $element.click vs $('element').click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to optimize parts of my code, I'd like to know which one of the following should I use and why, what is the benefit of one over the other?

```
$('element').click(function() { /* do something */ })
```

or

```
let $element = $('element')
$element.click(function() { /* do something */ })
```

Comment: They are identical for all intents and purposes. You are micro-optimising.

Comment: If you need the element reference in other parts of the application, caching it in a variable is surely a good idea, instead or repeat the same $('selector') again

Comment: Its a good option to use the var $element = $('element'); As if the further code requires the use of the $element it will  be resuable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between them is that in the second one, you have a variable that has a reference to the jQuery object, which you could reuse. You only need that if you want to reuse it, e.g.:

```
let $element = $("element");
$element.click(function() { /* ... */ });
if (someCondition) {
    $element.addClass("whatever");
} else {
    $element.find("some-child").remove();
}
// ...
```

Repeating the `$("element")` part in the above would be a bit more typing, and would require looking up the element(s) in the DOM repeatedly and creating new jQuery objects repeatedly, which would be less efficient than reusing the same object.

Sometimes you don't need a variable, since jQuery's API is designed for chaining. (Which is why I threw in the `if` above, so I could just do `$("element").click(/*...*/).addClass(/*...*/).find(/*...*/)` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on one question mainly for me - will I use that selector again?

If the answer is yes, then yes, define the variable to use and use it for the `.on` function and wherever else, if it's only once, then it uses more characters to define it and use it then to just use it. But there's no huge difference (unless you opt with method 1 and reuse selectors throughout)

Answer (score -1):

if the element is referred one or two times means **option1** is better.
but if the element is referred multiple times means **options 2** is better because you are diving into the dom only once even though it is referred multiple times and it will improve the performance and good coding practice